# Sorting in excel within a pivot value

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

In excel, sorting by the Row/Column labels allow you sort by the "Total" amount for that metric. For example, if I want to sort by the "Grand Total" SUM in USD, I can do:

[image]

How would I sort within a particular value of a column? For example, if I wanted to get Sum of Sales in usd in the "US" column --

[image]

Is there a way to sort by values within a particular column?

Comment: You should be able to do the same for the US column. I'm using windows but I think the process would be similar, just right click a value within the US column and select sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right click where the content of the column you want to sort is.

Then `Sort` > `Sort Smallest to Largest`/`Largest to Smallest`

I'm using Excel from MS Office 2013.