# Doing a Filter within a sub-value in a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table

This is a follow-up to the questions here, [Sorting in excel within a pivot value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57899783/sorting-in-excel-within-a-pivot-value), which is asking about how to sort within a column in a pivot table as follows:

[image]

Now that the data is sorted how would I do the following:

1. Get the "Top 2" items by this value --> This would eliminate the "Drama"  row.
2. Get all rows HAVING value (in column) > 500,000 --> This would eliminate two rows "Drama" and "Documentary".

How would I do these two things in Excel?

---

As an update to clarify, I am aware of the ability to add in a Top N or Value Filter within the Row/Column labels:

[image]

I am particularly asking how to do this exact same thing within a specific non-total column, "Sum of Sales in usd". How would this be done?

Comment: Have you tried to google your query as there are many tutorials on how to sort/filter in a pivot table in MacOS. How about give a read of this [article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-pivottable-cc1ed287-3a97-4e95-b377-ddfafe79fa8f#OfficeVersion=macOS)?

Comment: @TerryW right, but in doing a Top 10, how would I apply that within a particular column value? I've only seen the option to do Top N within a column/row itself and not a sub-value within it. Same with doing a Filter on a top-level value (i.e., grand total) and not a sub-value within it.

Comment: @TerryW question updated with more clarity.

Comment: @TerryW shown here (updated) -- https://gyazo.com/5d8de6480b248e212f36115077f7c2e2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using windows but I believe you can do the same in MacOS.

Please note applying same filter for multiple columns may fail so it is best to do the filter for one column at a time.

[image: Steps]

Comment: thanks for this. I've tried doing the same thing actually, but then as soon as you un-do that filter, it un-sorts it. It's needed that I can sort by a particular column, but have the context of all the other columns as well.

Comment: @David542 say you have sorted the US column descending, then you apply the filter on the column label to show US column only, and then apply the filter on the row label to show the top 2 result. If you later remove the filters on the row label and column label, the US column remain sorted descending. So I am not too sure what do you mean by `un-sorts it`. As I said filter for multiple columns will fail as you cannot ask pivot table to show the first two rows for one column and show the last two rows of another at the same time.